# Access Google API directly from Blazor WASM PWA

Tags: c#, .net-core, google-drive-api, progressive-web-apps, webassembly

Although I can access my Google Drive API via Blazor *Server-side* using the Google API libraries and my service account json credentials, I'd like to be able to have my end users access the drive files directly via the *WASM PWA* application (not through a user interface to Drive, but  for my app to automatically pick the files to download/upload on a user-initiated "update") -- when NOT connected to my server back-end, and without hosting the client/server app on a separate service.

However, it seems that the Google libraries do not support the WASM platform. I tried creating JWT tokens directly on the WASM side (JWT namespace) , but the cryptography libraries (System.Security.Cryptography) needed to convert the Json private key are also not supported on WASM (Error: System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates is not supported on this platform.). I'm not trying to hack google, just looking for an efficient, user-friendly, and flexible way to get to the Drive files when offline from the server back-end.

Is this possible, or do I need to go through my server backend?

Comment: I am struggling with the same issue. When I call GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync I get an error saying: System.Net.Sockets is not supported on this platform.